# Introduction to symmetries in physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

What are the topics that i should read after doing a course on classical mechanics,covering most of Goldstein {except continuum mechanics}to learn {more,as a beginner} symmetries related to classical and quantum mechanics?Is there any mathematical prerequisite for this?

Comment: “Is there any mathematical prerequisite for this?” It’s almost impossible to accurately discuss symmetries without at least the basics of group theory.